# why does sql date conversion from YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD not fail?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

This works, but why? How's YYYYMMDD acceptable as YYYY-MM-DD?

```
select to_date(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_date()` is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51077) to ignore punctuation under this circumstance:

> The following additional formatting rules apply when converting string values to date values (unless you have used the FX or FXFM modifiers in the format model to control exact format checking):
>
> - You can omit punctuation included in the format string from the date string if all the digits of the numerical format elements, including leading zeros, are specified. For example, specify 02 and not 2 for two-digit format elements such as MM, DD, and YY.